# IBM Worklight - load a properties file from an adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I need to access some properties from a Javascript adapter.
I know that i can access to *worklight.properties* file using

```
WL.Server.configuration.propertyName
```

but seems that when the property file change a server restart is needed

From Eclipse console after saving a new version of *worklight.properties*:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.005 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://hostname:hostport/ProjectName/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application ProjectName has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.007 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://hostname:hostport/ProjectName/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application ProjectName started in 1.868 seconds.
```

There is a way to avoid server restart, or use a different WL mechanism to read Server side properties?

My env:

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 2
>
> IBM Worklight Studio 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you do not explain why this server restart bothers you.

In the development environment - the Worklight Studio plug-in for Eclipse, what you say is correct - whenever you change any file that resides in the `server` folder of your Worklight project, the embedded WAS Liberty profile server will restart.

This is the expected behavior and is unavoidable.
In addition, there is no other mechanism AFAIK to read server properties.

Comment: The server restart is not an issue in the development environment but seems to be a potential issue in a production one. 
As you say is directly related to WAS Liberty profile and it's unavoidable. If this is true for any file that resides in the _sever_ folder we have no chance to fix it less then use a different Application Server.

Comment: This will not happen in production because in production you will need to deploy the war file, and by then you should set your mind on the project properties you want to use. And if you do want to change war files then there are procedures you need to follow to update the server.

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to avoid the server restart and access properties from file. You can follow the below work around.

- From Adapter you can access JAVA code
- From JAVA code try to access properties file

Am not sure why you are looking for some other mechanism above mentioned is just a workaround which am using in my project.